# ol v.2.13 - Selecting features with draw or zoombox

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I'm attempting to add a feature to a legacy mapping project. I need the user to be able to draw a rectangle and have the features/markers inside of it selected and pushed into the selected array. Is there an easy way to go about doing this? I would be fine simply adding a select feature to the already existing zoomBox function to make it easier. I've had difficulty implementing the examples I've seen and am new to OpenLayers. I'm working in ol v. 2.13.

Answer (score 1):

For future seekers of ol knowledge, I found the answer using the SelectControl control, which has a hash of attributes including two booleans that were pertinent to my problem: 'box' and 'multiple'.

The docs are here: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature